# Swift: multithreaded Array sorting

Tags: arrays, multithreading, swift, macos, sorting

I currently have a custom sorter function which is quite complex and thus takes time to execute. The `Array` I am sorting is comprised of custom `NSObjects` and can have up to several thousand elements. This is an OS X project (10.10+).

Is it possible to sort the array on multiple threads concurrently to speed up the process? I am currently using `sortInPlace(_:)` where the `isOrderedBefore` is a custom function that returns `true` or `false` depending on the order.

What's more, would it be possible to monitor the progress of the sorting with the multithreaded method (and if there is such a method)? This would be in order to update a `NSProgressIndicator`.

Thanks!

Comment: You could perform your sorting function in a background thread which then calls a method in a main thread that updates your `NSProgressIndicator`

Comment: Okay, this would be for the last part (getting the progress). How do I know the total number of times the sorter function will be called by `sortInPlace`?

Comment: my guess would be that you have to estimate the number of sorting passes and use an average number for the size of the array, since the number of passes is probably not same for different arrays of the same size

Comment: Okay I could try to analyze the correlation between the length of the array and the number of passes. My question for parallelization still stands. Thanks

Comment: Since you can't use sort from multiple threads on a same object, because you would probably end up with overlaps and probably exceptions or errors, I would try to fragment the array to smaller arrays, sort them first in multi thread, and after that sort join the array and sort it again, since this would already be sorted in a way it should take less time to sort it fully. You could also do a second run on less smaller fragments of array, and so on, depends on your array

Comment: I don't really see how pre-sorting chunks of the array would speed up the final sorting... Isn't that totally dependent on my sorting function? If you think this could work can you please post an answer with some sources, code and benchmarking results? Thanks